# Clarification needed on hydraulic disc caliper and lever compatibility

Tags: disc-brake, compatibility, hydraulic

I have a Scott Solace road bike that uses Shimano BR-RS805 hydraulic disc calipers.  The hose spec is BH 59. I want to change from drop handlebars to Jones H handlebars.  I will need new brake levers.  Can I use a mountain bike hydraulic brake lever with a hose spec of BH 90 and use BH 90 hose, if I use the olive and insert for BH 90 on the lever end, and the olive and insert for BH 59 on the caliper end?

Comment: Use the correct olive and barb for the hose at both ends.

Comment: The olive is the same for both. The insert is not though, I believe BH90 has a 2.1mm internal diameter compared to BH59’s 2.3mm. They are not cross compatible! The BH90 insert is silver. The BH59 insert is brass-colored.

Comment: Thank You JoeK - I will make sure I use the correct barb.  Thank You MaplePanda - I will try to find a lever specced with BH 59 hose to match my caliper.